# Django: how to order query set by OneToOneField's date?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two classes:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    ...

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.OneToOneField(
        Foo,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        primary_key = True
    )
    ...
```

How can I order `Bar's` objects like this:

```
query_set = Bar.objects.all().order_by('-foo.date')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access foreign key value by `__`
Something like this

```
query_set = Bar.objects.all().order_by('-foo__date')
```